# google.cloud.storage allows access but gcsfs does not

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to connect to a bucket on Google Cloud storage using `gcsfs`. So far I have only been using the native `google.cloud` module but it turns out I actually need file like objects for a certain application so had to switch over.

My `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable points to a JSON file on my local filesystem. Using `google.cloud`, I am able to access a bucket in cloud storage with no issues. However using `gcsfs` I am not. Here's some code to show what I mean:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import gcsfs
import google.auth

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(...)
blob = bucket.blob(f'data/audio_wav/test.wav')
bts = blob.download_as_bytes()

credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=..., token=credentials)
folders = fs.ls('data') #throws error
```

As commented, the very last line throws what appears to be an authentication error:

> google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.', {'error': 'invalid_scope', 'error_description': 'Invalid OAuth scope or ID token audience provided.'})

I would think that if `google.cloud.storage` accepts my credentials, then so should `gcsfs`. Why do I get the above error, and how can I fix it?

Alternatively, is there a way to open a file like object using `google.cloud.storage` and not `gcsfs`?

### JSON file

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": ...,
  "private_key_id": ....,
  "private_key": ...,
  "client_email": "ai-dj-884@ai-dj-76527.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "113487991001810308893",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/ai-dj-884%40ai-dj-76527.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the output from this command `cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. Remove the `private_key` in the update. If the JSON is valid, then the service account specified in the JSON does not have a required role. My guess is that the command will fail or is pointing to an invalid file type. The JSON should include `"type": "service_account"`. If you see the key `client_secret` you are using the wrong credential type.

Comment: Done. Please let me know if it helps

Comment: Delete specifying credentials. Change to: `token=None` to let the client find the credentials.

Comment: Another suggestion use `credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

Comment: A quick reminder that Stack Overflow is not a chatroom, and brevity/technical writing is preferred. This helps cut down the work that volunteer editors need to do - have mercy on us!

Comment: I sometimes offer this useful advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Answer (score 3):

As @John Hanley suggested in comments modify the mode of authentication (i.e., “token”) from "token=credentials" to "token=None", to use your default gcloud credentials or, attempt to get credentials from the Google metadata service, or fall back to anonymous access.

Refer to [Credentials](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#credentials) for more information.

To open a file using ‘“google.cloud.storage’” instead of "gcsfs" you can use the below method,

```
#create storage client  
storage_client = storage.Client('json-file-path’')  
#get bucket with name  
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('bucket-name')  
#get bucket data as blob  
blob = bucket.get_blob('file-name’)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is with the scope of your credentials.

As @John Hanley mentioned you can use the 'googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform' scope, this will not give you any scope errors, but your permissions are the only thing preventing the service account from accessing Google services.

The snippet below uses the GCS Readonly scope so will not work if you want to write back to GCS.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import gcsfs
import google.auth

credentials = google.auth.default()
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only']) # This is what you are missing
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=..., token=scoped_credentials)
folders = fs.ls('data')
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @Pietervdw is great, but doesn't work anymore in 2024 (Google Auth Library == 2.25.2).

Updated code looks as follows:

```py
import gcsfs
import google.auth

PROJECT = ...
BUCKET= ...

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only'])
fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project=PROJECT, token=credentials)

file_list = fs.ls(BUCKET)
```

It allows to read GCP buckets registered with different project than the one in `gcloud auth login`